# Python: How to config crontab to run a script in a virtual environment

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, python

I'm newbie making cronjobs with linux. My goal is to execute a python script in its own virtual enviroment.

To do this I have made first a shell script called **twitter.sh** where its content is:

```
source /home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/robot2-rss/venv/bin/activate 
python /home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/robot2-rss/main.py R,1
```

And its route is:

```
/home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/robot2-rss
```

We have access to source and python commands due their routes */usr/bin* are included in the PATH variable as you can see in the next image:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
```

The config of my cronjob is:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/1 * * * * /home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/robot2-rss/twitter.sh
```

However, this configuration of my cron job doesn't works and I don't know what am I doing wrong :(

**Edit I:**

I have modified my twitter.sh script to this new code:

```
#!/bin/sh

/home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/robot2-rss/venv/bin/python /home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/robot2-rss/main.py R,1
```

If I run the script directly works fine but with the cron job doesn't work!!! :(

**Edit II:**

How in the last modification from twitter.sh I just only was calling to my python script, I have modified my cron job to call directly to the python script like this:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
* * * * * /home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/robot2-rss/venv/bin/python /home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/robot2-rss/main.py R,1
```

And it doesn't work :( I don't know what happen :(

Comment: Could you replace the images with text? Not everybody, and not every software tool, can read pictures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**set a proper shell**

edit twitter.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=....
source /home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/robot2-rss/venv/bin/activate 
python /home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/robot2-rss/main.py R,1
```

be sure to set PATH.

**log result of command**

in crontab add login part

```
*/1 * * * * /home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/robot2-rss/twitter.sh >> /var/log/twitter.log 2>&1
```

if something goes wrong, you can have a look at `/var/log/twitter.log`

Comment: Thanks @Archemar!!! Your solution has help me a lot!!!

Comment: where should we set PATH to?

Comment: @Fayaz this depend completly on your context